# Location of certificate database (SSLKEYR) for Queue Manager (IBM MQ) not persisted

Tags: ibm-mq

I was successful in setting up the IBM MQ Docker container (9.2.2.2.0-r1-amd64) and creating a channel that allows me to connect to a queue using SSL certificates.

The issue I'm experiencing is that whenever I restart the container the queue manager "forgot" the location of the certificate database.

After I rerun `ALTER QMGR SSLKEYR('/var/mqm/qmgrs/QM1/ssl/QM1')` it works again.

Is there a way to persist this setting so that it survives the restart of the Docker container?

Comment: Is there any chance that the queue manager has a start up script that is running an `ALTER QMGR` command that is reverting the value of your `SSLKEYR` parameter? For example look in `/etc/mqm/config.mqsc`

Comment: IBM Docs also say that the `runmqsc` log of the configuration being applied is stored in the errors directory of the queue manager, as a file called `autocfgmqsc.LOG`. So you could also look in there to see what has been done by a start-up script.